# How to prevent backup for files larger than 3MB?

Tags: backup

One of the emacs's nice features is [Backup](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup.html).
But is there any way to prevent backup for files larger than 3MB?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [advising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) `backup-enable-predicate`, or setting it to a custom function which [checks the size](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Attributes.html) of its argument?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but here's an example of how you could [advise](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) `backup-enable-predicate` so that your [size check](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Attributes.html) happens only after the default `backup-enable-predicate` has determined that your file should be backed up:

```el
(add-function :after-while backup-enable-predicate
              (lambda (file)
                ;; Back up FILE only if it is smaller than 3 MiB.
                (< (file-attribute-size (file-attributes file)) 3145728)))
```